# Trim a list of different sub strings from a string which is part of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

So, I have imported data through DictReader from a csv file. This is an example

Name       Att1   Att2   Att3
c.45fs>96
c.67fs*>87
c.89fs*98

Now, I want to remove the portion after "fs*" or "fs*>" or "fs>". I tried this

```
for entry in data:
val = ['fs>','fs*','fs*>']
for i in val:
if i in entry['Name']:
entry['Name'] = entry['Name'].split(i)[0] + i
```

But this not working. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With regex substitution:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import re

s = '''Name       Att1   Att2   Att3
c.45fs>96
c.67fs*>87
c.89fs*98'''

with StringIO(s) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
    pat = re.compile(r'(fs\*?>?).+$')
    for r in reader:
        r['Name'] = pat.sub('\\1', r['Name'])
        print(r.values())
```

Sample output:

```
odict_values(['c.45fs>', None, None, None])
odict_values(['c.67fs*>', None, None, None])
odict_values(['c.89fs*', None, None, None])
```